# Laravel 5.3 query builder: 'NOTLIKE' not working

Tags: laravel

I have a table that has a column named version that has four rows containing values

```
|Version |
|--------|
|5.3     | 
|5.2     | 
|5.3     | 
|5.2,5.3 |
```

I want to get rows that's values are not like `5.2` I mean, I want to get the first and third rows not second and fourth rows.

I used Eloquent Model 'Menu' to make the query as below.

```
$query = Menu:where('version', 'NOTLIKE', '%5.2%')->get();
$numberRows = count($query);
```

`$numberRows` equals to `0`.

Am I in the right way? Or, is there any other way to do this? 
I need help.

Comment: Try adding a space, 'NOT LIKE'.

Comment: it should be `NOT LIKE` instead of `NOTLIKE`

Comment: You maybe want to rename `$query` to `$menus` because `get()` returns a `Illuminate\Support\Collection` (a collection can contain more than one item, so it is plural `s`) and not a query instance. Plus you should use `$menus->count()` then, staying in OOP-ed world. Documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-count (latest version)

Answer (score 26):

Change NOTLIKE to **NOT LIKE**

Correct code:

```
$query = Menu::where('version', 'NOT LIKE', '%5.2%')->get();
$numberRows = count($query);
```

Comment: As @aaronf mentioned, a double-colon is required  which you also miss. I cannot add it as stackoverflow doesn't allow such small changes. Please fix it, then this answer can be accepted.

Answer (score 5):

By the way you need a double colon `::`.
Your code should then be

```
$query = Menu::where('version', 'NOT LIKE', '%5.2%')->get();
$numberRows = count($query);
```

Answer (score 3):

You are missing a space between not like clause.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#where-clauses

Answer (score 1):

Your error is this `'NOTLIKE'` resolve this `'NOT LIKE'`

try this:

```
$query = Menu::where('field', 'NOT LIKE', '%5')->get();
$query = Menu::where('field', 'NOT LIKE', '5%')->get();
$query = Menu::where('field', 'NOT LIKE', '%5%')->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to add a space in between NOT LIKE so it will look like this

```
$query = Menu:where('version', 'NOT LIKE', '%5.2%')->get();
$numberRows = count($query);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  $query->where('field', Auth::user()->id)
                  ->orWhere('field','NOT LIKE', '%,'.Auth::user()->id.',%')
                  ->orWhere('field','NOT LIKE', '%'.Auth::user()->id.',%')
                  ->orWhere('field','NOT LIKE', '%,'.Auth::user()->id.'%');
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to give a space between NOT and LIKE, so it will look like this

```
$query = Menu:where('version', 'NOT LIKE', '%5.2%')->get();
```